# How to produce Typescript output to correct destinations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs, jasmine

I am re-implementing existing functionality with Typescript, and I would like to use Jasmine for testing. I had started using Jasmine with Javascript specs, but that feels wrong. Now I try to use Typescript specs (which feels right), but I am not able to find the right configuration to produce the javascript files at the correct locations.

I am using:

- Grunt
- Jasmine
- Typescript

with the following structure:

```
/base_dir
  /src
    *.ts files
  /src-spec
    *.ts files (only specs)
  /spec
    *.js files (generated by typescript compiler I hope)
  /lib/js
    *.js files (generated by typescript compiler as well)
```

I have currently defined the following configuration for Grunt:

```
ts: {
  libs : {
    src: ["src/*.ts", "!node_modules/**"],
    outDir: 'lib/js',
    options: {
        keepDirectoryHierarchy: false,
        rootDir: "lib/js"
    }
  },
  specs : {
      src: ["src-spec/*.ts"],
      outDir: ['spec'],
      options: {
          rootDir: "spec",
          keepDirectoryHierarchy: false
      }
  }
```

But the resulting directory structure is the following:

```
/lib/js/*.js files   // produced correctly
/spec/src/*.js       // same content as /lib/js
/spec/src-spec/*.js  // the corresponding spec file
```

And when I run Jasmine, the spec file in `/spec/src-spec/` does not find the libraries located in `/lib/js` and `/spec/src`.

What is the recommended solution here for

- setup of directories
- parameters used for compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the recommended solution here

Personally I like a single `tsconfig.json` for IDE integration. Everything inside `src` (including tests) with `outDir` to `lib`. Finally simply `.npmignore` `lib/tests`.

## More

The organization for `src` and `lib` is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: The answer gave me the right starting point, I have added another answer just to illustrate my solution then (not following `tsconfig.json` recommendation).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @basarat gave me the right direction, here is the solution that fits my question above:

Change the structure to:

```
/src
  *.ts        (app files)
  tests/*.ts  (test files)
/lib/js
  *.js        (generated app files)
  tests/*.js  (generated test files)
jasmine.json   (configuration for the changed paths)
```

`jasmine.json` had to be changed to:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "lib/js/tests"
  ...
}
```

`Gruntfile.js` has to be changed to:

```
jasmine: {
        exec: 'jasmine.cmd JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=jasmine.json'
    }
```

After that, all files are compiled as usual, go to the right place, and references from app files to others and spec files to app files are stable.